# Id value 0012800000CyJVI is not valid for the Contact standard controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

Id value `0012800000CyJVI` is not valid for the Contact standard controller 
how to check wrong id in apexpage and show error in salesforce? using standard controller

Comment: You need to post the code in your controller so that we can help you better...

Comment: Salesforce checked the Id, it was invalid, and an error message was displayed. What did you want to do differently?

Answer (score 6):

**like you error says**..`0012800000CyJVI`..

I believe you are using wrong Id for Contact standard controller. You need to use Id which is start with `003`.

**Looks like we can't catch this error in try catch.**

**Note**

if any id starts with `001` means it is **Account Id**

If id starts with `003` means **contact Id**

If You want to check the Id is related to which Sobject..

Use like below snippet

```
Id strId = '0039000001pHWrO';

system.debug('=======check sobject Type====='+strId.getSobjectType());
```

`getSobjectType()` return the object Type

**Logs**

```
18:35:51:068 USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|=======check sobject Type=====Contact
```

Comment: @SachinGoyal you can't check in javascript.. Else check in your apex class and returnn that id.

Comment: how can i enable the chat option  chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34542/…

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using wrong id. This id(*0012800000CyJVI*) is an *Account* id(every id that starts with *001* is an account).

If you want to check that the id that you have is of correct type you should use `Schema` object. And example:

```
if (yourId.getSObjectType() == Schema.Contact.SObjectType) {
    System.debug('This is a contact');
} else {
    System.debug('This is NOT a contact');
}
```